# CKEditor doesn't post data if I have an input type='file' in form

Tags: ckeditor, text-editor, rich-text-editor

I am trying to use CKeditor plugin as HTML text editor. But the problem is if I have an `input type="file"` then when I submit the ckeditor plugin doesn't post the text I wrote inside it. But If I remove the `input type="file"` from my form then it works fine.

I need to have both in my form. Could you please tell me how to get both work fine?

Thanks

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>support_admin/plugins/ckeditor/ckeditor.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<form action="something">  
<label>Details</label>
<textarea class="ckeditor" name="article" ><?php echo $articles; ?></textarea><br>

<label>Image 1</label>
<input type="file" name="imagefile1"  /><br>
<button class="button" style="margin-left: 200px;">Submit</button>      
</form>
```

Comment: Is that all your code? At the very least I would expect a 'enctype="multipart/form-data"' in the form to upload a file. Maybe there's something else in your page and that's the problem.

Comment: @AlfonsoML thanks for your reply.  No that's not all, I have other codes too(like jquery plugin for menu..). And I also have `'enctype="multipart/form-data"'` in my form. I changed the file type to text and then I got it worked, but again when I tried with the input type as file, it didn't work. thanks :)